# A circuit question using multiple MOSFETs with PWM control

Tags: mosfet, pwm

I need to PWM control two electromagnet groups where each group has four electromagnets. Emagnets have nominal 24V 0.33A current ratings. [Here](https://www.schukat.com/schukat/schukat_cms_de.nsf/index/FrameView?OpenDocument&art=ITS-MS5030-12&wg=E4351) is the only datasheet I could find. To supply all the magnets I want to use [this](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/8157450/) 24V 4A single power supply. To model these, I drew the schematics in my mind and simulated it as follows:

[image]
(left-click to view/enlarge)

To model emagnets each drawing 0.33A current, I used 72Ohm and 1u inductor. I also added [1N4148](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81857/1n4148.pdf) as a flywheel diode to each magnet.

The idea is two PWM outputs of a micro-controller like Arduino's will control(by two potentiometers as analog inputs of the uC) each two groups's PWM input hence the magnet current. Since the uC does not have 8 separate PWM outputs, each PWM is triggering four gates of the MOSFETs as shown in the diagram above.

In simulation I obtain the following power plot for this [MOSFET](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91019/91019.pdf) I plan to use:

[image]

I have the following questions as concerns before I start soldering:

**1-)** Is it fine as in my diagram to connect all the gates at a point and trigger four MOSFETs from a single input?

**2-)** Are the gate resistors values for R_g1, Rx_1, R_g2, Rx_2 correct/sufficient?

**3-)** It seems I wouldn't need heat sink by looking at average power dissipation. But I wonder if I should change the PWM frequancy. Currently it is 490Hz. Would it make sense to increase it to 30KHz for instance to prevent ringing sound or another issue?

**edit:**

Using a non-inverting driver [TL427](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21415c.pdf):

[image]

**edit2:**

I reduced MOSFETs(one for each group) and diodes(I used 1N4007)

[image]

Here is the power plot for one transistor in between 1.15ms and 1.2ms:

[image]

Comment: Nooooo! Don't parallel MOSFETs without individual gate resistors. It will be batch dependent and you may have failures in the field sporadically. Last time I missed this and the product passed all type tests, the failure rate at the customer was in the high tens of precent.

Comment: Please see my edit2 I now use one MOSFET and one diode for each group. TL427 is powered by 9V supply. I would be glad if you have an input.

Comment: Much better! Is 1N4007 up for the job?

Comment: Do you mean 1N4007 can be slow? I guess I should stick with 1N4148 since I might increase pwm freq. (?)

Comment: Yes. Might be fast enough for your application, but I still ask leading questions. Voltage rating, peak current rating and trr needs to be matched to your particular situation. Also, diodes are dirt cheap, even the fast ones.

Comment: Next thing is I should figure out if I need heat sink. I afraid these magnets might make ringing noise so if I increase PWM to 30kHz(to eliminate noise) the FET's power dissipation will be high. I guess better to add heatsink anyway. (?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67305/discussion-between-winny-and-161776).

Answer (score 1):

> 1-) Is it fine as in my diagram to connect all the gates at a point and trigger four MOSFETs from a single input?

Technically yes you can wire MOSFETS in parallel like that and they will work. However, you need to remember that the gate of a mosfet is effectively a capacitor. As such, four in parallel is four times the capacitance. That means the switching time of the four gates will be roughly four times slower than using a single device.

> 2-) Are the gate resistors values for R_g1, Rx_1, R_g2, Rx_2 correct/sufficient?

They look fine, and typical, to me.

> 3-) It seems I wouldn't need heat sink by looking at average power dissipation. But I wonder if I should change the PWM frequancy. Currently it is 490Hz. Would it make sense to increase it to 30KHz for instance to prevent ringing sound or another issue?

Higher PWM, assuming you can switch the MOSFETS that fast, will cause more heating losses in the MOSFETS and reduce the efficiency of the circuit. At some frequency point you will need a heat sink. It will however reduce the audible effects. There is a compromise in there somewhere that you need to figure out. Either way you need a frequency high enough so that the ripple on the current through the inductors is fairly small.

Comment: I can use heatsink anyway but I don't know why the ringing sounds happens. Is that do you think something to do with the PWM frequency being the harmonic of whatever natural resonance frequency of the magnet coil? I also dont want to use extra component like MOSFET driver IC. Finally you wrote "you need a frequency high enough so that the ripple on the current through the inductors is fairly small" I didnt understand this. Which ripple? How would it be an issue?

Comment: Do you  think it is better to use bipolar transistor like TIP120 instead of MOSFET for this application?

Comment: @161776 The changing current in the inductor and magnet causes mechanical vibration. In your case at 490Hz. The magnets act like really bad speakers. Raising the switching frequency does two things. 1. It attenuates the amount of noise the mechanics can make due to their inherent inertia, and 2. raises the frequency beyond human hearing range. Note we go to like 50 because some animals can still here over 40.

Comment: How about using a logic level MOSFET like this one: http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/14b7/0900766b814b79a0.pdf with a lower on resistance, so I think I could increase the freq to 12kH or more safely ?

Comment: @161776 in general, if you use a bipolar transistor your base current required will mean the stage driving it needs to also be more powerful. However, .33A load current is not much so a decent bipolar would work ok in this application.

Comment: @161776 run different design methods in a simulator and see which one works out best.

Comment: In sim the current from the pwm outputs approaches to 20mA at full duty cycle. This is a bit scary. Can I increase R_g1 and R_g2 to limit this current caused by the gate capacitance of the MOSFET? Or should I go for a MOSFET driver?

Comment: @161776 yes those resistors should be chosen to limit the current to whatever the previous driver can safely supply.  Increasing them does slow down switching. Whether you should go to a MOSFET driver is open to opinion, or you may want to consider adding a higher current buffer IC in there if you need to reduce the gate resistance.

Comment: Please see my new circuit here or in my question's edit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8FaI.png Do you think this is on the safer side now? I would be glad to have your opinions.

Comment: @161776 that will be faster, and you may be able to get rid of the series resistor, but you still have the 20nF of gate capacitance to deal with. Note the Microchip part's ratings are quoted at only 1nF. You would do better with one decent MOSFET for each channel.

Comment: I will reduce R_g1 and R_g2 to 10 Ohm. But how about using a single MOSFET for each group(for each 4 magnets)? It might sound crazy but I just thought of it. Maybe 8 MOSFET not necessary?

Comment: @161776 yes there is no particular need for four unless you have some other reason to isolate them, and your load currents and not large.

Comment: I added the last version edit2